# Largest multi quadratic intermediate field

Tags: galois-theory

Let $L/K$ be a finite field Galois extension and $n\in\mathbb{N}$ be maximal such that there is anis $n$-quadratic intermediate field $L'$. Can one relate  $n$ to the Galois group of $L/K$, in particular to a $2$-Sylow subgroup?